# Flashlight Enabling for a video call

Tags: stock-android, ios, video-calling, flashlight

As far as I know, there is no support for flashlight while we are chatting via video call in a smartphone. Why it is not present? Is there any hardware limitation? Can someone explain?

Answer (score 0):

As of now, Android doesn't provide any option to enable flashlight during video calls.

Examples for [iPhone and Blackberry](https://crunchise.com/turn-flashlight-on-off-iphone-android/) are here.

The Mi forum question "[How can i turn on front flash during video call - Redmi Y1 - Mi](https://c.mi.com/thread-604933-1-0.html)" says option #3 works. Another thread "[[Q & A] How to start Selfy Light During Video Call????](http://en.miui.com/thread-1514434-1-1.html)" claims it's a known problem and that you can fix it by resetting your phone and not enabling Face Unlock.

There's no reason the light shouldn't work and you can stand near a white wall or reflective surface to get enough light at night to make a video call. If you edit your question to include a specific phone model we may find a specific set of instructions for your phone.

If nothing works you can get around it by purchasing a "[Phone USB Light](https://www.bestbuy.com/site/poser-snap-mini-led-smartphone-light-black/5591857.p?skuId=5591857)":

[image: Alibaba]

[image: BestBuy]

Comment: I am using Redmi Y1. Also I have tried in Lenovo K8 Plus. No good results.

Comment: @Dhans - Thanks for your reply. I've updated my answer with a couple of forum threads which seem to disagree on the answer. I've also added a guaranteed to work solution which costs between a few and 10 bucks depending on which model and where you buy it. If nothing works a USB LED will, maybe better and brighter - LEDs use very little power but it will affect 'Talk Time', as does video calling over SMS. I hope one of these can work for you.